# Hyperlinks from one XPS document to another

Tags: url, browser, hyperlink, xps

A number of our XPS documents contain links to other pages. These hyperlinks work fine from the browser, however they refuse to open links to **other** XPS documents.

When clicking a URL to another XPS, we get the error: "The XPS viewer cannot open this link."

We've tried using a link to another page that contains a  redirect to the document - but still no joy.

Can anyone help? We love working with XPS but this is the only thing holding us back.

Thanks